# Event listener to delete individual markers when they are clicked, only acts on last created marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hello and thanks in advance for your help!

The following test code:

1) Uses PHP to get lat/lng data from a mySQL database, and then uses that data to form a JavaScript array with initialization data.  WORKS FINE.

2) Uses the initialized JavaScript array to create markers.  WORKS FINE.

3) Allows (left) clicks to create new markers (more code will be added later to add those new marker locations back into the database).  WORKS FINE.

4) Allows RIGHT-clicks to delete a marker using marker.setMap(null) - either the preloaded markers from the database, or newly created user markers.  USER MARKERS DELETE PROPERLY, PRE-LOADED MARKERS DO NOT DELETE PROPERLY, AS DESCRIBED BELOW.

5) Both the preloaded markers, and the newly created ones are stored in the array "markers" using the statement markers.push(marker).  SEEMS TO BE OK.

Everything works, except the right-click deletion of the PRELOADED markers.  (The right-click deletion of user created markers works fine.)  Any right-click on any preloaded marker, only deletes the LAST preloaded marker.  It's as if the delete event listener were outside and after the loop that sets the preloaded markers, but it is inside that loop.

I think the faulty section is the one with the leading comment "show prev clicks in database".  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  I'm very new at Google Maps API v3, so it's probably something obvious that I'm just missing or misunderstanding. Thanks again!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Marker Test</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #map-canvas, #map_canvas {
                height: 100%;
            }

        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

<?
// Generate JavaScript array initialization from database

$username="REDACTED";
$password="REDACTED";
$database="REDACTED";

$con=mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database,$con) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query="SELECT * FROM pool where (record_id >= 1765) AND (record_id <= 1769)";
/*
$query="SELECT * FROM pool where (record_id <= '$marker_end') AND (record_id >= '$marker_start')";
$query="SELECT * FROM pool where session = '$session'";
*/
$result=mysql_query($query,$con);

$length=mysql_num_rows($result);
$length_count=1;

if ($result) {
    echo "var PreviousClicks = [\n";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_lat=$row['google_lat'];
        $_lng=$row['google_lng'];
        $_record_id=$row['record_id'];
        echo "{\n";
        echo "lat: $_lat,\n";
        echo "lng: $_lng,\n";
        echo "title: \"$_record_id\"\n";
        echo "}";
    if($length_count<$length) {echo ",\n";} else {echo "\n";}
    $length_count++;
    }  // end while
    echo "];";
}  // end if
mysql_close();
?>

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var markers = [];

function addMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    title: "A",
    map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
    marker.setMap(null);
    });

    markers.push(marker);

}  //end addMarker function

function initialize() {
    // currently manual center initialization
    var startLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(33.037380,-117.090431);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: startLoc,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TRAFFIC
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });

// show prev clicks in database    ------------------------------------------------------------------            

    for (i = 0; i < PreviousClicks.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(PreviousClicks[i].lat, PreviousClicks[i].lng),
            title: PreviousClicks[i].title,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });

        markers.push(marker);

    }  // end for

// end "show prev clicks in database" section ----------------------------------------------------

}  // end function initialize

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to alert the marker object and see its attributes are coming properly or not for the particular marker on which you are performing right click.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a marker's event handler, `this` refers back to the marker. Therefore :

```
this.setMap(null);
```

will remove the marker from the map.

But more can be done with this code. In particular :

- Avoid repeating code by using `addMarker()` to add both new and previous markers.
- When markers are removed, also remove them from the markers array.

Both can be achieved as follows :

```
function addMarker(event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: event.title || "A",
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function(event) {
        this.setMap(null);

        //Remove the marker from the markers array.
        for(i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
            if(markers[i] == this) {
                removed = markers.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
function initialize() {
    ...
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addMarker);
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < PreviousClicks.length; i++) {
        addMarker({
            latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(PreviousClicks[i].lat, PreviousClicks[i].lng);
            title: PreviousClicks[i].title
        });
    }
}
```